# Проблема с OAuth Facebook Authenticator на Symfony 4.3

Tags: php, symfony, facebook, oauth

Пытаюсь подключить аутентификацию через facebook на тестовом сайте на Symfony 4.3
После клика на кнопку войти через facebook меня просто кидает обратно на страницу логина безо всяких ошибок и предупреждений. Полазив по отдадчику обнаружил такую интересную вещь: запрос даже не доходит до FacebookAuthenticator!!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, он проверяет App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator - не подходит, затем проверяет App\Security\OAuth\FacebookAuthenticator - тоже не подходит, хотя должен подходить!

Вот фрагмент security.yaml

```
    guard:
        authenticators:
            - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            - App\Security\OAuth\FacebookAuthenticator
        entry_point: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
```

Вот метод supports класса App\Security\OAuth\FacebookAuthenticator

```
public function supports(Request $request): bool
{
    $this->logger->info("Check this 1986: ".$request->attributes->get('_route'));
    return $request->attributes->get('_route') === 'oauth.facebook_check';
}
```

Кстати в логгер мне пишет это:

```
[2019-11-26 13:05:18] app.INFO: Check this 1986: app_login [] []
```

При попытке подменить роут oauth.facebook_check на app_login symfony пишет мне ошибку "Invalid state parameter passed in callback URL."

Вот часть из моего шаблона:

```
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <a class="btn btn-block btn-facebook" href="{{ path('oauth.facebook') }}">
                                <span>Log in by facebook</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Вот контроллер:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller\Auth\OAuth;

use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class FacebookController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route(path="/oauth/facebook", name="oauth.facebook")
     * @param ClientRegistry $clientRegistry
     * @return Response
     */
    public function connect(ClientRegistry $clientRegistry): Response
    {
        return $clientRegistry
            ->getClient('facebook_main')
            ->redirect(['public_profile']);
    }

    /**
     * @Route(path="oauth/facebook/check", name="oauth.facebook_check")
     * @return Response
     */
    public function check(): Response
    {
        return $this->redirectToRoute("home");
    }
}
```

Почему метод supports класса App\Security\OAuth\FacebookAuthenticator не срабатывает??? Ведь текущий роут должен совпадать с роутом, когда я кликаю по кнопке "Log in by facebook".

Comment: В `supports` вам приходит роут `app_login`  а он и не совпадает с `oauth.facebook_check `

Comment: Alpha, я вижу. Вопрос: почему? Ведь я перехожу по href="{{ path('oauth.facebook') }}" который в браузере превращается в url /oauth/facebook

Comment: Добавьте полностью security.yaml